# Is it possible for Java apps to use the Aero Glass effect?

Tags: java, swing, windows-vista, aero

Is it possible for a Swing based Java to have the Aero Glass effect as the background under Windows Vista/7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is possible, as it was achieved by the person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627683/combining-aero-glass-effects-and-swt). I am currently researching the same thing and will post here if I find out how.

Comment: After further research, no. The built-in API for Swing applications doesn't have built-in aero compatibility.

Answer (score 11):

As of Java SE 6 Swing's native look and feel for windows uses Aero.  There's a blog post with a lot of details about this from Chet Haase entitled [Java on Vista : Yes it works](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/archive/2006/10/java_on_vista_y.html)

Comment: The blog posts contain screenshots that show window titles in unreadable gray instead of the normal black, and show some graphics glitches: Note the right borders of the minimize/maximize/close buttons of the inner windows here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/96dpi_swingset2.png

Comment: @Zarel: It may be because the article is dated oct 2006. By now ( Java 6 update 14 ) it works just fine. I remember I had an screenshot of it.

Comment: There are some other screenshots in this JavaLobby post that show darker window titles - http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t78880.html?start=30

Perhaps in Chet's the app was sent to the background by the screenshot software, he had a horrible color scheme set, or it was an earlier beta version of Java 6SE.

I'd validate it with some screenshots myself but currently on my Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

It does already.

[alt text http://img167.imageshack.us/img167/5655/capturaxk5.png](http://img167.imageshack.us/img167/5655/capturaxk5.png)

From this [unrelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542844/how-can-i-make-joptionpane-dialogs-show-up-as-a-task-on-the-taskbar/543012#543012) answer