# True Transparency in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is this possible to make aero frame in java swing application?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Is it possible for Java apps to use the Aero Glass effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107283/is-it-possible-for-java-apps-to-use-the-aero-glass-effect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/).

Answer (score 0):

As for Java 6 or older, using classes from 
    import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;

Java 7 has added these two new methods for Swing.

```
JFrame.setUndecorated(boolean);//wont work if the frame is decorated
JFrame.setShape(someShape);//set frame shape
JFrame.setOpacity(somefloat);//set frame tranparency
```