# Combining Aero Glass effects and SWT

Tags: java, windows, swt, aero, aero-glass

As a pet project, I've been playing with the concept of integrating Aero Glass effects into my SWT application. [Łukasz Milewski has an excellent blog post](http://www.milewski.ws/2009/02/vista-glass-in-swt-application/) explaining how this can be accomplished, which pretty much boils down to this:

```
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());
final MARGINS margins = new MARGINS();
margins.cyTopHeight = -1;

final Composite c = new Composite(shell, SWT.NORMAL);
c.setBackground(new Color(shell.getDisplay(), new RGB(0, 0, 0)));
final FormData fd = new FormData();
fd.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
fd.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
fd.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
fd.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
c.setLayoutData(fd);

OS.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(shell.handle, margins);

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
```

This works beautifully, until you want to add a control. This results in black remaining transparent:

[image: Transparent shell with control]

[A follow-up post](http://www.milewski.ws/2009/05/vista-glass-in-swt-application-continuation/) demonstrates how to do this, too, but requires modifying the SWT library. (At least, I believe so, because private SWT functions are overridden with `@Override`.)

How can I avoid controls becoming transparent? Even better: how can I benefit from transparency (e.g. placing images on it [like so](http://www.milewski.ws/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/vista-glass-swt.png)), but use it in a sensible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overridden methods are "package private". In order to override them without compile time errors, you have to put your classes into the same package as the super class, i.e. `org.eclipse.swt` or `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package. The blog you cite post actually mentions this implementation detail at the end, so I don't know, it this really answers your question.

Comment: I simply read right past that. Surely enough, that allows everything to compile without any problems, but there are plenty of things still not working correctly. A fully working example would be great, because only by setting some constants and some additional cases in `callWindowProc()` can I get `OpaqueText` to indeed display opaque text. I'll update my question with my current code in the morning.

Comment: Since the bounty is expiring, I'll award it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your control beyond glass area or try to use force Background color for the control.

Comment: Placing my control outside of the glass area more or less defeats the purpose of the effect. I don't consider "avoiding black" a realistic option, either. I know there's a way of doing this correctly (a colleague mentioned resolving a similar issue in C#), so I'll just keep crunching on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned by the solution that overrides internal methods, but you are using an internal SWT class in the first place. This seems like a very hacky fragile way (at least in the current SWT implementation) to add some eye candy to your app... I hope you are not doing this in production code.

Comment: Wrapping it in a `try { ... } catch (Throwable e) {}` surely can't hurt. It's just eye candy, so if it fails, no biggie, right? There are some `OS` references in current production code, implemented like that. Is it really very bad practice?

Comment: It's also not so much a *concern* of mine to be overriding private methods; it's more that I just can't get it done without compile errors. What am I doing wrong?